# scheme: how to use call/cc for backtracking

Tags: scheme, callcc

I have been playing around with continuations in scheme (specifically guile) over the last couple of days and am a little puzzled by the results that some of the functions have and was wondering if anyone could explain exactly what is going on here.

There is a function called `(get-token)` that will retrieve the next found token in a given file. For example, if the next 3 tokens were "a", "b", and "c", calling (get-token) would return "a" the first time it is called, "b" the second time it is called, and "c" the third time it is called.

What I would like to do is have a function `(peek-token)` that will call `(get-token)`, return the token, and then return to a state before the `(get-token)` function was called. I have attempted a number of different methods to achieve this result, and the one I currently have is:

```
;; make things a little easier to write
(define-syntax bind/cc
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((bind/cc var . body)
     (call/cc (lambda (var) . body)))))

;; function should return next token and then
;; revert to previous state
(define (peek-token)
  (bind/cc return
           (let ((token (get-token)))
             (return token))))
```

How I understand it right now, the `bind/cc` will save a continuation at the first `return` and then execute the following block of code. Then when `return` is hit again, the program jumps back to where the continuation was bound and the `token` value is given as a result.

However, when I run the above function the results are exactly the same as the original `(get-token)` function.

I would be very grateful if anyone could explain where I am going wrong, or express a better way to get the same result (I know some people hate going the way of call/cc).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To hack a Mark Twain misquote to pieces: The reports of `call/cc`'s capabilities are greatly exaggerated.

More specifically, `call/cc` captures *call state*, not *program state*. That means that it captures information about where the flow of code goes when the continuation is invoked. It does *not* capture information on variables, and in particular, if your `get-token` saves its iteration state by `set!`ting a variable, that is not going to be restored when you invoke your continuation.

In fact, your expression of `(call/cc (lambda (k) (let ((token (get-token))) (k token))))` should behave identically to simply `(get-token)`; there should not be any observable differences between the two expressions.

Comment: Thanks a ton for clearing this up. I ended up putting the `(peek-token)` function inside of my scanner file and am just keeping track of the file pointer so I can re-read tokens from it. Just out of curiosity, do you know of a way to capture the actual program state in either scheme or CL? Or is there never really a need for this?

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken anything of the form `(call-cc (lambda (k) ... (k x)))` is exactly the same as `(begin ... x)`.

Comment: @jozefg Pretty much, assuming that that's the only place the continuation is used.